# Apex trigger is not being trigger when record is created indirectly?

Tags: salesforce, apex-trigger

I made an apex trigger which purpose is to be triggered everytime a cartitem is created or deleted.
This works when create it directly in the database, but when I do it indirectly as user on trying to buy an item from my store (b2b commerce (LWR)), the trigger does not get triggered.

It like its being ignored in the store?
any idea?

I have no debug logs to go by, since it is not being triggered at all, but the condition for it to be triggered has been fulfilled.

This is the trigger:

```
trigger SetSerial on CartItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {

        // List to store Cart IDs that need to be updated
            Set<Id> cartIds = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
            System.debug('Hello World!');
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "LWR store"? You have an experience (formerly known as community) running on Lightning Web Runtime? You tried to put debug logging on "{site name} Guest User" and really nothing is captured? are the records created from standard components or custom UI? Maybe the user doesn't have rights to execute some classes?

Comment: I have a trigger that should be triggered everytime a new cartitem is created, or deleted. 
The trigger code only have a system.debug message that is being printed. 

When I delete the record from the database I see the message in the debug.log 
but when I do by adding an  product to my webcart via the browser, nothing happens. 

I see no debug messages.

Comment: And are these cart items really inserted? Record id is generated, you can see them as normal records as internal user? I won't be surprised if the cart is just some in memory JavaScript thing (session storage?) And they get saved only when you go to checkout or something... You'd have to inspect more code. Is it all custom written in your org or some installed package or what, SF b2c e-commerce?

Comment: A record is insert ed to the database, with a unique id

Comment: No idea, sorry man. You could even raise a SF support case. What's the record's created by? Normal community user? Guest user? "Automated user"? Could you put debug log on that user? Maybe it uses some platform event shenanigans and you'd have to debug somebody else. What if you do something stupid like put a validation rule or new required field, will it save too?